# What technologies and programming languages should I learn to do this?

Tags: deployment, backend

I want to create a website that allows users to create an account, and be able to post on it.

Now I have a one year experience in front-end web dev, I know HTML/CSS/JS. I can create basic websites such as portfolio website ...etc.

So what should I do next in order to be able to create a full website that interacts with the user and grabs data for them and use it later?

Comment: Please checkout https://roadmap.sh/

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn some type of backend technology. try searching for full stack development. there are several "stacks" out there. LAMP (Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP) for example. Currently full stacks like MEAN and MERN are very popular. Essentially, you need a server, a database on that server to hold data, and something on the server like NodeJS or PHP to act as a 'server' to answer requests. Try searching for REST API's and full stack development. be careful though because for instance, if you use the MERN Stack (MongoDB, Express, Node, React) your site may not be SEO friendly. You may want to learn something like NextJS (a framework built on React that can act as both front and backend) if SEO is important to you. Either way, learning React would be a very good thing for you to do, as it is very popular. Concerning your original question, about the backend, NodeJS is where I would start, as it will allow you to program in JavaScript for the Front end and the back end. NodeJS is just Chrome's JS runtime for servers and development. If all of this is over your head, I recommend watching yt videos about the history and trends in web application development. And learn JS deeply. You cannot do anything on the web without it. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a "full website" that interacts with the user and grabs data for them you will need to learn about API's and the backend. Put that all together with your front-end and you have your full-stack Development as you will be doing everything. If you are familiar with HTML/CSS/JS you should research some stacks that handle everything you are looking at. I would recommend before building your full-stack website, getting some practice with API's and the backend. Practice grabbing data from the user, storing that information in a database, and having that database work with your website. You should do a bunch of practice first before you just start building a full-stack website.

You can find information on a very popular full stack called MERN here: https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/mongodb-tutorial/what-is-mern-stack-introduction-and-examples

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a full-stack website with a server and database as well as your front-end UI.

You'll need the back-end, with a REST API and database models, to store user information and keep track of all your data.

The most popular tech stack out there is called MERN, and it stands for MongoDB, ExpressJS, ReactJS, and NodeJS. You can find an in-depth article on learning MERN technologies below:
https://thelonecoder.dev/javascript/mern-stack-roadmap/